# React Native: How to setup automated integration tests?

Tags: testing, react-native, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'm new to testing and I've been given a task to set up and write automated integration tests for React-Native app for both iOS and Android.
I'm having a serious trouble setting up integration tests. What frameworks should i use? I've found some tutorials but they felt mostly outdated. Is using Appium with Travis CI viable? I've found some examples using Mocha and Chai to write tests. (http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2015/11/08/react-native-integration-tests/ this seems like the best one). I really appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guide to automation framework in detox : React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837274/guide-to-automation-framework-in-detox-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you following integration test tool for react native: [Cavy](https://github.com/pixielabs/cavy)

Answer (score 1):

We've recently started using [Detox](https://github.com/wix/detox) from Wix which allows for gray box end-to-end testing of React Native apps. It also supports CI platforms like Travis.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample github repository for the POC task I did for automating React Native app e2e using [Detox](https://github.com/wix/detox) from Wix .Hope it will be helpful : https://github.com/saifsms91/DetoxAutomationPoc.

Moreover you can refer this Stackoverflow question for automating React Native App:

[Guide to automation framework in detox : React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837274/guide-to-automation-framework-in-detox-react-native)