# Guide to automation framework in detox : React Native? Creating End 2 end and integration testing framework

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, mocha.js, jestjs, detox

---

Automation testing on **detox** for **react native apps** to create E2E tests and integration tests.
Need suggestion on the following:

- Best Automation Framework that can be used TDD,BDD to avoid refactoring of code.
- How to create integration tests for Android and iOS using detox and jest
- Easy to use TestRunner Mocha or Jest or any other.
- Any reporting mechanism once the test has been executed.
- Any POC on detox automation for e2e testing with CI/CD.
- Design Pattern like POM how to use it for React Native
- Any Sample detox repository with step by step approach to integrate it with RN app.

**Note:** I have already installed the required dependency need in **detox** with **Mocha** from [Wix](https://github.com/wix/detox) git repo and successfully launched the demo project.Looking for a Framework template that I can use it as a reference in designing my own framework.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for [jest together with detox](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Jest.md). You can use the same test executer for unit and integration tests by [configuring projects in jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#projects-array-string-projectconfig). This way you can execute them in the same run. CI/CD for detox is [documented well](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.RunningOnCI.md) and works great for iOS. Android is still not possible on the most common CI/CD platforms

Comment: what about webdrive.io ?

Comment: I have no experience with webdrive.io, do they also automate mobile application interaction?

Comment: sorry, webdriver.io, yes they do, using appium to interact but it's transparent when writing the test.