# How to start using detox

Tags: detox

Im completely new to JavaScript Programming and want to start writing tests for UI Automaiton of react native apps using detox.
Can someone tell me if it is possible to write tests just the way we do it in Appium or do we have to have NPM Project for the app cloned first?

Comment: Are you asking do we need a source code to write UI tests in Detox unlike Appium where we only need .app file for iOS and .Apk file for android then yes since detox is a grey box UI automation tool.Refer this should be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837274/guide-to-automation-framework-in-detox-react-native

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guide to automation framework in detox : React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837274/guide-to-automation-framework-in-detox-react-native)