# Can I use detox test framework to test react + react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, detox, velo

Totally New this area:

Does [Detox](https://github.com/wix/Detox) support apps which are developed in React and Wrapped in ReactNative?

I am trying to use testing framework for react+react-native app. Trying to test in simulator and/or device. I liked [Detox](https://github.com/wix/Detox), but not sure if it will work with app which is developed in react and wrapped in react native.

If it does work then wondering if testID in component which are in react (not react native) will be recognized by Detox or not?

Don't have app yet couldn't test yet. Looking at the wix/detox github doesn't mention specifically for this scenario.

My other option is to go with Appium, but would love to go with Detox if this works better and Supported by WIX.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Guide to automation framework in detox : React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837274/guide-to-automation-framework-in-detox-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

Detox is built specifically to test React Native (Which is always accompanied by React), and it uses the testID property to access the components, so you should be all set.

You can read a bit about its differences from Appium [here](https://medium.com/@reime005/react-native-end-to-end-testing-d488e010e39f), and why it is recommended.

Comment: Thank you @filipe. Should this testID be part of react component or react native view? I would want to use it in react component if that works.  Thank you for sending that link I had already gone through it before :).

Comment: @user8828251 you can use the testID in any React component (Custom components that you created, components from libraries, or React Native components)