# How to end-to-end testing a react native app?

Tags: windows, react-native, cypress, detox

I have a react NATIVE app I would like to test in a end-to-end way. First, do you know if Cypress can do it ? I'm really not sure of it but in doubt I ask anyway. Second, I've seen Detox can do it but I have a Windows environment and it seems Detox is only supported by Mac or Linux. Do you have any solutions for my problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guide to automation framework in detox : React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837274/guide-to-automation-framework-in-detox-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your React Native app is developed.  You *might* be able to use Cypress for E2E testing.  If you use Expo and Expo for Web, Cypress can test much of the functionality of your app.

Please see this blog and demo: https://justinnoel.dev/2019/12/27/e2e-testing-of-react-native-apps-using-cypress/

Answer (score 1):

**Detox For windows** you have to change the gradlew command in the "build" key in `package.json`
because it is prepared for mac environment to make it work for you on windows for example for android:
https://github.com/jmr85/react-native-detox/blob/master/package.json

```
"android.emu.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "android / app / build / outputs / apk / debug / app-debug.apk",
    "build": "cd android && gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType = debug && cd ..",
    "type": "android.emulator",
    "name": "Nexus_9_API_28"
},
"android.emu.release": {
    "binaryPath": "android / app / build / outputs / apk / release / app-release.apk",
    "build": "cd android && gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType = release && cd ..",
    "type": "android.emulator",
    "name": "Nexus_9_API_28"
}
```

Another tool using Mocha, Webdriver.io client and Appium server ... is similar to Selenium

Answer (score -8):

Cypress can perfectly do it. It is a tool easy to learn and provides a lot of debugging possibilities that no other tool will deliver.

You can find important information to help you to decide adopting Cypress or not in this FAQ session: https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq.html

I've worked with Selenium and Protractor in the past and I would definitelly suggest Cypress. You can check all Cypress features here (the Game Changers session really deserves the name): https://www.cypress.io/features.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: From FAQ: "Cypress will never be able to run on a native mobile app, but we do intend to support mobile web browsers in the future. Down the road we’ll likely have first class support for this, but today it is not a current priority.". You effectively helped me to confirm cypress is not the solution for me, thank you :)

Comment: Nice :) But sorry for the "Cypress can perfectly do it." part lol.