# Writing test case for react-native component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have never written test cases so I am totally not sure on how to achieve this (and have never worked with travis as well).

I have [react-native-formly npm library](https://github.com/irohitb/rn-formly) written entirely in javascript.

Every time dependent bot creates a request, before merging, I want it run test cases and only merge if the app loads and does not crashes. I have seen other open source repo have travis.yml which they used to achieve this but it is still vague to me on how I could achieve it.

Can someone guide me on how to achieve this? what kind of test cases/library I should use. I know there are libraries like jest for snapshot testing but I don't care much if the UI renders differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a PR for your repository. https://github.com/irohitb/rn-formly/pull/14

This will be quite a long answer, as the question lacks focus, since it's asking for react native jest setup, CI/CD and TDD which could take up multiple Q&A.

---

> Every time dependent bot creates a request, before merging, I want it run test cases and only merge if the app loads and does not crashes. I have seen other open source repo have `travis.yml` which they used to achieve this but it is still vague to me on how I could achieve it.

- Travis CI - you can follow the [tutorial](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/)
- for Circle CI - [getting-started](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/getting-started/)
- for cypress - [e2e cypress](https://justinnoel.dev/2019/12/27/e2e-testing-of-react-native-apps-using-cypress/)

> Can someone guide me on how to achieve this? what kind of test cases/library I should use. I know there are libraries like jest for snapshot testing but I don't care much if the UI renders differently.

In this PR - we have introduced `jest` and `react-native-testing-library`.
`jest` is the standard React testing suite which is similar to mocha/chai/assert in the node ecosphere.
`react-native-testing-library` - allows us to query components and the value/text render that the component should have. You can find more [info](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library) or the [docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/getting-started)

---

in the PR - we have included one test to get you setup, you should be able to continue with the other components.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-native-testing-library";

import { InputText } from "../formComponent/text";

describe("render app components", () => {
  it("should render text", () => {
    const props = {
      upsideEmit: () => {},
      textInputStyle: [],
      value: "Hello World",
    };
    const component = render(<InputText {...props} />);

    expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(component.getByDisplayValue("Hello World")).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

We're able to

**1. assert whether the component.toJSON matches the snapshot**

```js
expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

**2. given props with value `"Hello World" we can assert that the displayValue is rendered.**

```js
const props = {
  upsideEmit: () => {},
  textInputStyle: [],
  value: "Hello World",
};
const component = render(<InputText {...props} />);
expect(component.getByDisplayValue("Hello World")).toBeDefined();
```

---

in relation to how you test your components - you should be able to:

1. check if the component renders.
2. determine based on the props, that the component renders.
   2.1. `success` case.
   2.2. `error` case.
   2.3. normal case.
3. You may want to add integration tests (e.g. userflow 
   `render component` -> `interact with component` -> `check above test cases`) more details in terms of libraries can be found on this previous [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834230/react-native-how-to-setup-automated-integration-tests)

Comment: Denis, one of the component in my library is image-picker which requires native implementation. How can I write test cases for that?

Comment: @iRohitBhatia native tests would probably be placed under a new question btw. This question is getting quite large. I’d rather split the effort into a new question. (I’d be happy to help there)

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of end-to-end test if you want to run the app, and ensure it doesn't crash.

Have a look at Cypress (http://cypress.io) or webdriverio (http://webdriver.io)

Cypress has docs on setting up with CI/CD https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Setting-up-CI

Edit... Sorry I missed the react-native part.  The above would work for web apps, have a look at something like Detox for React Native (https://github.com/wix/Detox)

Comment: Andy, The description says: `Fast, easy and reliable testing for anything that runs in a browser`. Does it work with React Native also? I wasn't able to find any RN tutorial/post for the same. (Updated the title of my stackoverflow question)

Comment: i updated the answer for react native